# what is the real return value/type of mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Some people say that the return type of `mysql_query` is true/false

But it doesn't make sense in the following two codes

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");
// the parameter in mysql_fetch_array is true/fale ? wired ?
$result = mysql_fetch_array(**$result**);
```

actually, my question includes what dose a resource mean ?  a pointer?

does resource similar to pointer ?

Comment: How about [reading some documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to answer this for yourself?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

[From Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: actually what does resource/resultset mean ?

a pointer ? or a reference

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php for details on resource.

Comment: [**mysql_query** http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)